# Remove border in selected tab in eclipse juno using the css theme

Tags: eclipse, gtk, themes, eclipse-juno

In the Ubuntu GTK Eclipse Juno theme, the selected tabs have a grey bottom border. I would like to remove this border. How can I do this?

**I am NOT asking *how* to create, edit, or modify an eclipse theme**. I am looking for the *specific* CSS styles required to remove the border.

Here is a screenshot of the selected tab with the border in question:

[image]

See that pesky grey border under *Tab3*? Yes. What CSS can I use to remove that border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

http://hwellmann.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/fixing-editor-tab-fonts-in-eclipse-juno.html

which explains how to get an E4 CSS editor and also says the change needed is:

```
.MPartStack {
    font-family: "Droid Sans" ;
    font-size: 9;
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

which works for me.

The file /eclipse/plugins/.../e4_default_gtk.css did not change - I eventually found:

```
$HOME/.e4css/e4_default_gtk.css
```

which does have the updated CSS.

Comment: Does this remove the bottom border? The article talks about "oversized and truncated labels in all editor tabs", it says nothing of the border and the before and after shots clearly show the bottom border on the tab. I also tested the CSS and it doesn't remove the bottom border for me?

Comment: Protip, remove any CSS files with "default" in the name. Why are they doing this to us? Doing the same with more resources... who was like "we need CSS!" I'd like to shove the cloud down their throat